# Can hydrogen peroxide dissolve rust?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, redox

[WD-40's "help page" on "How To Loosen Rusty Bolts, Screws And Nuts"](https://wd40.co.uk/tips-and-tricks/how-to-loosen-rusted-and-seized-nuts-and-bolts/) states:

> Hydrogen peroxide can dissolve rust. Applying hydrogen peroxide to the
> fasteners and letting it sit is also an effective method to remove
> rust and loosen nuts and bolts.

I'm no chemist, but most of what I've found in the last couple of hours tells me that hydrogen peroxide is more likely to cause (create) rust than "dissolve" (remove?) it, for example, see LibreText: "[Hydrogen peroxide is considerably stronger as an oxidizing agent than as a reducing agent](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/11%3A_Reactions_in_Aqueous_Solutions/11.20%3A_Substances_Which_Are_Both_Oxidizing_and_Reducing_Agents)".

Can someone who understands these things please let me in on what happens when I mix rust and hydrogen peroxide? Is it true that *"applying hydrogen peroxide […] is also an effective method to remove rust […]? I find this claim dubious.

Comment: I think its action is mostly mechanical - it decomposes and bubbles disrupt layers of rust.

Comment: Also, it's mostly water and that helps a lot in terms of getting stuff into solution.

Comment: @Mithoron Are you saying that "there is no _reaction_ between rust and hydrogen peroxide" (as far as you aware)?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt But rust is insoluble in water (at least that's what a few posts on stackexhange would have me believe!)

Comment: Rather than dissolve read disrupt. That is not a chemistry book. The statement makes sense, context given. Let me add that iron is a catalyst for hydrogen peroxide decomposition, so the latter should be vigorous at the right place.